# Using Groovy's JsonSlurper for actual POGO mapping?

Tags: json, groovy

I've seen countless examples of [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) used to parse JSON text and create a "JSON object" out of it:

```
def jsonObject = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonText)
```

But what if the JSON text represent one of my `FizzBuzz` objects? Can I use `JsonSlurper` to map the JSON object into a `FizzBuzz` instance? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After parsing JSON with `JsonSlurper` You receive a `Map`. If `FizzBuzz` has a `Map` (see [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-lists-and-maps-as.html)) constructor it should work when parsed `Map` is passed to constructor.

See the following example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = """{ "name": "John", "age": 127 }"""
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def person = parsed as Person

assert person.age == 127
assert person.name == 'John'

class Person {
    String name
    int age    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - two followup questions: (1) my `FizzBuzz` instance does not have an explicit constructor, so it depends on the default ctors that Groovy provides; **does this mean I have a map ctor?** And (2) What if I have another object that I want `JsonSlurper` to map, but that object (let's call it `Widget` has a few explicitly defined constructors on it? **In such a case, can `JsonSlurper` still be used?** Thanks again!

Comment: If no constructor is provided at all Map constructor will work. In the second it will not work in all cases.

Comment: Ok. So You need to provide empty constructor or no constructor at all to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for checking up on that @Opal (+2) - so if I have explicit-value (non-default) constructors, then I would have to use a JSON mapper such as GSON or Jackson to handle the mapping?

Comment: Yes, or use `JsonSlurper` and use appropriate constructor passing values from map e.g. `new SomeObject(parsed.key1, parsed.key2)`